# CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnNotificationReceived android event not firing

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, firebase-cloud-messaging

I can successfully send notifications to my app using the [Google Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/), but the open event never fires (Android emulator running in Visual Studio 2019)

This is my **MainApplication.cs** file, simplified for brevity:

```
public class MainApplication : Application
    {
        public MainApplication(IntPtr handle, JniHandleOwnership transer) : base(handle, transer)
        {
        }

        public override void OnCreate()
        {
            base.OnCreate();
            CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Init(this);
            
             // these events fire as expected
            CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnTokenRefresh += (s, p) =>
            {
            };
            CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnNotificationReceived += (s, p) =>
            {
            };
            // this doesn't
            CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnNotificationOpened += (s, p) =>
            {
            };
```

I'm using the [FirebasePushNotificationsPlugin](https://github.com/CrossGeeks/FirebasePushNotificationPlugin) and my code is based on the samples that they provide.

Xamarin and mobile development is completely new to me and because I'm not sure where the issue lies, I'm reluctant to post reams of code, most of which might be irrelevant. However as some of the events the work and others don't, that seems a good place to start.

**UPDATE - for clarity I've added some additional info:**

I also have a **SplashActivity.cs** which has the `MainLauncher = true` attribute:

```
public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState)
{
     base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
     Log.Debug(TAG, "SplashActivity.OnCreate");
    
     FirebasePushNotificationManager.ProcessIntent(this, Intent);
}
    
    ...
    
protected override void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
{
      base.OnNewIntent(intent);
      FirebasePushNotificationManager.ProcessIntent(this, intent);
}
```

There is also **MainActivity.cs** which has this:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
     TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
     ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

     base.OnCreate(bundle);

     Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, bundle);
     global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
     LoadApplication(new App());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

currently this is how it works for me
add in the main application inside the onCreate this:

```
     CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Init(this);
     //Set the default notification channel for your app when running Android Oreo
                if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.O)
                {
                    //Change for your default notification channel id here
                    FirebasePushNotificationManager.DefaultNotificationChannelId = "DefaultChannel";
    
                    //Change for your default notification channel name here
                    FirebasePushNotificationManager.DefaultNotificationChannelName = "General";
                }
    
                //If debug you should reset the token each time.
    #if DEBUG
                FirebasePushNotificationManager.Initialize(this, true);
    #else
                    FirebasePushNotificationManager.Initialize(this, false);
    #endif
                CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnNotificationReceived += (s, p) =>
                {
                   
                };
            }
        }
    }
```

and in the main activity this:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            FirebasePushNotificationManager.ProcessIntent(this, Intent);
        }

        protected override void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
        {
            base.OnNewIntent(intent);
            FirebasePushNotificationManager.ProcessIntent(this, intent);
        }
```

Comment: That's exactly the code I did have, but following the answer from @jack-hua-msft I've moved it to SplashActivity (where the `MainLauncher = true` attribute is)

Answer (score 1):

I think your activity is not the main launcher activity.

Declare the `FirebasePushNotificationManager.ProcessIntent(Intent)` on your activity with `MainLauncher = true`.

Please read more threads to get more information:

[OnNotificationOpened never executed.](https://github.com/CrossGeeks/FirebasePushNotificationPlugin/issues/32)

and

[CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnNotificationOpened Event is not firing](https://github.com/CrossGeeks/FirebasePushNotificationPlugin/issues/40)

Comment: You're correct, it was in `MainActivity.cs`.  I moved it to `SplashActivity.cs` but unfortunatley there was no change.

Comment: Are you following the steps in this [comment](https://github.com/CrossGeeks/FirebasePushNotificationPlugin/issues/32#issuecomment-333573151)?

Comment: To the letter, however the solution contradicts the code samples.  In the sample [SplashActivity.cs](https://github.com/CrossGeeks/FirebasePushNotificationPlugin/blob/master/samples/FirebasePushSample.Android/SplashActivity.cs), the `MainLauncher` attribute is true, yet the ProcessIntent code is still in `MainActivity.cs`

Comment: While I think what he said in the comment is set `MainLauncher= true` in `SplashActivity` and move `FirebasePushNotificationManager.ProcessIntent(Intent);` to `SplashActivity` too.